# SQL Case statement in WHERE clause to omit data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a generic query set up where I am `SELECT`ing a list of employees. If my param `searchType = 'omit`, I wan't to exclude people from showing up in that search by checking to see if they exist in temp table.

```
-- Params
@searchType varchar(10)

-- Temp Table
DECLARE @omit AS TABLE (userID INT)
INSERT INTO @omit( userID ) VALUES (123)
INSERT INTO @omit( userID ) VALUES (456)
INSERT INTO @omit( userID ) VALUES (789)

-- Query
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE userID NOT IN( 
    CASE 
        WHEN @searchType = 'omit' 
            THEN (SELECT userID FROM @omit ) 
            ELSE '' 
        END
)
```

In the above example, if I ran the procedure and passed `omit` as my param, it will select all employees where their `userID` does not exist in the temp table.

When I try this, it gives me an error of `Subquery returned more than 1 value`.

What is the best way to set this up?

Comment: The query `SELECT userID FROM @omit` return more than 1 row, so you better think of using `NOT EXISTS` instead

Answer (score 1):

So you only want to filter when you are passing in that parameter?

```
SELECT e.*
FROM dbo.Employees e
LEFT OUTER JOIN @omit o
    ON e.userID = o.userID
WHERE 
    (@searchType = 'omit' AND o.userID IS NULL)
    OR
    (@searchType != 'omit')
```

left outer join gives all records from table on the left of the join (employees) and only record on the right (omit) that match. This mean that when the parameter is 'omit' they cannot have a row in the omit table, other wise it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM dbo.Employees e
LEFT JOIN @omit o
    ON e.userID = o.userID
WHERE NOT (@searchType = 'omit' AND o.userID IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
 SELECT * FROM Employees a WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM @omit b
 where a.userID = B.userID AND @searchType = 'omit')
```

Answer (score 0):

Bookmark and read Erland's site. All of it when you have time. The relevant portion is [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) here. And perhaps think about searching the internet before posting - because this is a frequent topic.

In addition, you tagged "stored procedure" but did not include all of the code. The danger is omitting any code is that no one can see your datatypes, your assumptions, or how you interface with the procedure. In general, the more "generic" you attempt to make a given query, the worse it performs. Erland discusses this in addition to many ways of dealing with the variability of your search logic.